# How to add icons to emails in Outllook?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, icons

While [`Folder.SetCustomIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869281.aspx) can be used to customize folder icons, the only thing related to icons for messages seems to be the deprecated (and basically undocumented) [`mailitem.FlagIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.flagicon.aspx). Is there any way to have a custom icon shown next to emails in the message view, e.g. via a custom column? As an example, the gravatar (or identicon) associated with a sender's email-address might be shown left of the "From" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MailItem.FlagIcon` is very much documented - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211991(v=office.11).aspx - but is does not really apply in your case.

Outlook can show an icon in a few cases:

1. Set the `PR_ICON_INDEX` MAPI property (take a look at a message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - select a message, click the IMessage button, find the `PR_ICON_INDEX` property, double click to edit). You can set a couple dozen or so predetermined icons, that is how Outlook sets the replied/forwarded/etc. icons.
2. If you design a custom form, you can associate it with a custom icon. Outlook will show the icon based on the message class (`MessageClass` in OOM or `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS` in Extended MAPI). You can see `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS` in OotlookSpy (click IMessage) and the custom form data (click IMAPIFormMgr).

One thing you cannot do is show a custom icon programmatically based on an one-off icon set on the item itself.

Comment: Thanks, option 1 would of course eliminate the otherwise helpful information about RE/FWD/etc status, and one is limited to Outlook's icons - further reading: http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=2&messageid=25629 and I assume this boils down to FaceId, which can be found on http://www.outlookexchange.com/articles/toddwalker/builtinolkicons.asp and http://www.kebabshopblues.co.uk/2007/01/04/visual-studio-2005-tools-for-office-commandbarbutton-faceid-property/ and http://skp.mvps.org/faceid.htm. Sounds like fun...

Comment: Option 2 is nothing that can replace the native message pane, right?

Comment: No, the preview pane would still be there.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko when I use replace or replaceall it removes the preview pane content, how do you keep the form there along with icon when using separate or adjoining region form ?